# How to read an XML file present in a folder in the Silverlight project?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

While searching for the solution, I've come across various links which talk about reading an xml file present in the ClientBin folder. But what I want to achieve is that, I want to read an xml file which is not present in the web project, but the silverlight project containing views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        StreamResourceInfo s = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Directory Under Silverlight Root/FileName.xml", UriKind.Relative));

        var sr = new StreamReader(s.Stream);
        // do whatever you need to do with the streamreader
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            //do stuff


        }
```

**EDIT**: the xml file's Build Action should be 'Content' and its Copy to Output Directory should be 'Do not copy'